# Is it possible for an Eclipse plugin to be both Headless and make contributions to the UI?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, headless-rcp

I created a plugin that uses some cdt API to to fetch data about about all C projects in a Workspace. This plugin makes a contribution to the UI since you can click on a button to trigger this action.

I created another headless plugin (a rcp), that performs the same operations but is operating on headless eclipse and called by command line. I have 2 jar files, one for each of these plugins but I would like to have only one.

Is it possible to have a single plugin with a single jar files that can both make contribution to the ui and be called by command line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isWorkbenchRunning` method of `org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI` to test if the UI is running.

```
public static boolean isWorkbenchRunning();
```